# Passing None to open()

Tags: python

I have a context manager over a large chunk of logic that looks like

```
with open(file_name1, 'rb') as file1:
  with open(file_name2, 'a+b') as file2:
    logic_here
```

Unfortunately, there is an edge case where `file_name2` might be `None`. I still, however, want the `logic_here` to execute. Is there an elegant way to handle this without removing the context manager? It looks like I might need to resort to using a `try / catch` and manually calling `.close()` on the file.

I don't mind just opening any file as in theory, I don't care about the content of the writes that occur. I do want to avoid creating too many temporary files that I write to, and I do want to avoid accidentally writing on personal files that might already be on disk.

Comment: What exactly would you expect `file2` to be when there isn’t a second file? If your logic doesn’t depend on it, move the logic one level up.

Comment: When there isn't a second file, I don't care about what I am writing to the file. Sadly, a large portion of `logic_here` already relies on needing to call .write().

Comment: So you have lines `file2.write` in your logic but if `file_name2` wasn’t provided, you simply want to skip those automatically?

Comment: Skipping the writes would be the ideal behavior. I see that I could also scan the current directory and generate a unique ID that would correspond to a file generated by the program itself. However, I would need to write logic for tracking files generated by the program to avoid creating an excess number of temporary files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick, hacky solution, since that seems to be what you're looking for:

```
if file_name2 is None:
    file_name2 = os.devnull
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.devnull

Comment: I like this idea of handling it, if you put it into a function like @poke It seems reasonable, not even that hacky (well in terms of dealing with a problem that probably came from a hack)

Comment: Nice, didn't know that. I'd do `open(file_name2 or os.devnull, 'a+b')`, though. Shorter, doesn't change the variable, and would handle the empty string as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function that either returns the file object, or a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) object:

```
from io import StringIO

def openFileOrString (name, mode):
    if name != None:
        return open(name, mode)
    else:
        return StringIO()

with openFileOrString(file_name2, 'a+b') as file2:
    pass
```

Since StringIO is not a context manager in Python 2, you need to add a bit of boilerplate around it to make it work there. One way to do it would be to create a StringIO wrapper that is a context manager; a simpler way would be to just provide a new context manager that just uses the file’s context manager inside:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def openFileOrString (name, mode):
    if name != None:
        with open(name, mode) as f:
            yield f
    else:
        yield StringIO()
```

Comment: A `StringIO.StringIO` in Python 2 has no `__exit__`, so can't be used as a context manager.